# Can't select "All Filters" in LinkedIn after I get to People Search - Find_element does not work no matter what I try

Tags: python, selenium

Wrote simple python code to do the following: 
1.login into linkedin
2. click search, then people
3. click "All Filters" to further modify search

I am getting stuck on step 3 and am unable to get driver to select and click on "All Filters"

I have tried to find_element by xpath, however it is dynamic and changes
I have tried to find_element by text "All Filters" and still doesn't work

For some reason when I right click on "All Filters" button and click Inspect, it first takes me to  instead of the actual button; I have to right click - inspect a 2nd time to get to ; This makes me think the button is hidden and I am unsure of how to proceed.

```
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains  
import pynput.mouse as ms  
import pynput.keyboard as kb  
import time  

driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/akame/Documents/PythonFiles/chromedriver.exe")  
act = ActionChains(driver)  


driver.get ('https://www.linkedin.com/')  
driver.maximize_window()  




login_email = driver.find_element_by_id('login-email')  
login_password = driver.find_element_by_id('login-password')  
submit1 = driver.find_element_by_id('login-submit')  
mouse = ms.Controller()  
keyboard = kb.Controller()  

login_email.send_keys(‘XXXXX’)  
login_password.send_keys('XXXXXX')  
submit1.send_keys(u'\ue007')  

searchfield = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="ember49"]/input')  
act.click(searchfield).perform()  
act.send_keys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).perform()  
act.send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()  

time.sleep(5)  

#this is where it does not work--->  
button_af = driver.find_element_by_text('All Filters')  
button_af.click()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try code below, or just replace `button_af = driver.find_element_by_text('All Filters')` with `button_af=find_element_by_xpath("//span[@class='artdeco-button__text' and text()='All Filters']")`, cause sometime there's newline`\r` or `\n` in an element text, u should alway try to use `contains` instead of `==` to get an element's text:

```py
    from selenium import webdriver  
    from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  
    from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains   
    from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
    from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
    from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
    import time 


    email = "ur_email"
    pwd = "ur_pwd"
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()  
    act = ActionChains(driver)  



    driver.get ('https://www.linkedin.com/')  



    login_email = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
            EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "login-email"))
        )
    login_password = driver.find_element_by_id('login-password')  
    submit1 = driver.find_element_by_id('login-submit')  
    login_email.send_keys(email)  
    login_password.send_keys(pwd)
    submit1.click()

    searchfield = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@role='combobox']")))
    searchfield.click()

    searchKeywordXpath = "//span[text()='People']"
    searchKeyword = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, searchKeywordXpath)))
    searchKeyword.click()

    btnAllFilterXpath = "//span[@class='artdeco-button__text' and text()='All Filters']"
    btnAllFilter = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, btnAllFilterXpath)))
    btnAllFilter.click()
    # just debug code: wait to see the right page appear or not
    time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: @ninja-k then set my answer as the correct one（｡ӧ◡ӧ｡）

Comment: side question; do you know how to test certain code in the same window from where I left off? I am trying to see how new lines of code work for creating next actions and not have to run the whole code from beginning, which ends up opening a new window, logging in, repeating all the steps...etc. @Lau Real

is that kosher to ask unrelated follow up here? hah...or should I post a separate question?

Comment: @ninja-k yes, with [cypress](https://www.cypress.io/), u can sen requests to make preconditions done!